# See what Ubuntu1 folders are shared

Tags: ubuntu-one

I have several folders in my Ubuntu1 folder that I have shared to various people, and I can't remember which folders are shared with which people.  Is there an easy way to find that information?

Answer (score 1):

You can open a terminal and run `u1sdtool --list-shared` to see the list of folders you've shared with other people.